# How to generate pulses at 5khz with 0.01s duration and 0.09s delay?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I want to generate a continous pulse in Matlab. I would like to generate the signal at 5khz with a duration of 0.01s, then nothing for 0.09s and then starting again. It's kind of a rectangular pulse, except it's in 5khz.

I have the following code to output a waveform for 0.01s at 5khz,

```
function [ output ] = FreqGen(  )
%UNTITLED3 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
fs = 44100;
T = 0.01;
t = 0:(1/fs):T;
f = 5000;
a = 0.5;
output = a*sin(2*pi*f*t);
end
```

but I failed to figure out how to use Matlab function pulsetran to generate 0.09s pulses.

Just like the plot below:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't make sense; the period of a 5kHz waveform is 0.2 ms, i.e. 0.0002 seconds.  How does this tally with the numbers you're quoting?

Comment: I may be wrong on that. MOre general question is how to use pulsetran to generate waveform with another custom wave function?

Comment: Given your diagram, you want to generate a wave with frequency of 10 Hz, or 0.1 s.

Comment: @rayryeng: 10 kHz?  It seems to be a 5 kHz wave on-off modulated at 10 Hz (with a 10% duty cycle).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - Yes sorry my mistake.  I meant 10 Hz.

Comment: The Matlab documentation of pulstrain is actually really bad in terms of understandability, written by an engineer on a bad day.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes. Thanks for your detailed explanation. Do you have some suggestions on how to revise the code to implement the function above? Really appreciate your help again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now with `pulstran`.

A short documentation on `pulstran`. The syntax is:

```
y = pulstran(t, d, function_handle, p1, p2, ..)
```

and `t` are time steps for calculating the pulses (also the total time and dimensions of output), `d` are the pulse centers (shifting deltas) and `p1, p2, ..` are additional parameters to the function.

So the output is similar to the sum of `function(t+d(i), p1, p2, ..)` over all elements of `d`.

Here is the code:

```
function Untitled()

[t, y] = FreqGen(5e2, 20e3, 1, 1, 0.01, 0.1);
figure;
plot(t(1:3e3), y(1:3e3));
xlabel('time [s]');

end

function [t, y] = FreqGen(f, fs, T, A, Pulseduration, Interpulseduration)
% f - frequency of sine wave [Hz], fs - sampling frequency [Hz], T - total
% duration [s], A - amplitude of sine wave, Pulseduration [s],
% Interpulseduration [s]

% time steps
t = 0 : (1/fs) : T;

% pulse center steps
d = 0 : Interpulseduration : T;

% use pulstrans
y = pulstran(t, d, @my_pulse, A, f, Pulseduration);

end

function y = my_pulse(t, A, f, Tend)
% Sine pulse from 0 to Tend
    y = zeros(size(t));
    tx = t > 0 & t < Tend;
    y(tx) = A * sin(2 * pi * f * t(tx));
end
```

It's a bit slower though than the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28427726/1536976).

Comment: Trilarion, Thank you very much for providing two great answers. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of [pulstran](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pulstran.html) is not really helpful. While one could look into the function directly it is actually the easiest way to implement what you want yourself (and you circumvent the Signal Processing Toolbox). Here I did it:

```
function Untitled()

[t, y] = FreqGen(5e2, 20e3, 1, 1, [0.01, 0.09]);
figure;
plot(t(1:3e3), y(1:3e3));
xlabel('time [s]');

end

function [t, y] = FreqGen(f, fs, T, A, Tr)
% f - frequency of sine wave [Hz], fs - sampling frequency [Hz], T - total
% duration [s], A - amplitude of sine wave, Tr - duration of high/low state
% of rectangular envelope pattern [s]

% time steps
t = 0 : (1/fs) : T;

% first the sine wave
ys = A * sin(2 * pi * f * t);

% then the rectangular envelope
yr = double(mod(t, sum(Tr)) < Tr(1));

% multiply both
y = ys .* yr;

end
```

The rectangular envelope is calculated with the help of modulo and a comparison.

And it looks like:

[image]