# Pulsed Sine Wave in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

Could anyone help me identify the equations and the MATLAB code required to generate the plot in the following image? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What kind of equations would you like to receive? As a mathematical function and then a corresponding matlab expression?

Comment: That would be the ideal scenario. However, I encountered the solution posted in the following thread which seems to be what I'm looking for, but I am trying to understand the logic behind the line defined for the signal yr.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420084/how-to-generate-pulses-at-5khz-with-0-01s-duration-and-0-09s-delay?rq=1